# JWT tokens on .NET based on Active Directory

Tags: .net, active-directory, jwt

Active Directory and Authentication in general is not an area in which I consider myself an expert. Unfortunately, the task of maintaining a large .NET server application has fallen upon me and my customer has a question I need to answer.

The .NET application uses Active Directory to authenticate accounts. Upon initial login, it then generates a JWT token using JwtSecurityTokenHandler. I can tell that the lifetime of the token is being set to 60 days, and I can see where subsequent requests are decoding the incoming tokens in order to validate the requests.

The question my customer has is: What happens if they remove a user from Active Directory while that user has a valid JWT token? Will the token continue to work until it expires 60 days from its creation date, or will it stop working immediately?

My hazy understanding of the JWT mechanism suggests that the server is simply making sure that the token is properly signed and not expired whenever a request is made. I don't think it is re-validating the identity against Active Directory with each request. At least, I don't believe that Active Directory interaction is part of the JwtSecurityTokenHandler; if we were doing it, it would have to occur after the token is validated. Is this correct?

How do most applications handle this -- is it reasonable to validate every inbound request against AD to make sure the account is still valid, or will that add too much overhead?

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JWT is a self contained access token. Once issued, you cannot revoke it until it is expired. Yes, you will be able to access the authorized resources with the issued JWT access token even after the user is removed from the Active Directory until it is expired. To overcome this issue, a refresh token is also issued with the JWT in the authentication process. A refresh token can be revoked at anytime. Therefore, if the user is removed from the Active directory refresh token will be revoked.

The best practice followed is to set the access token validity for a shorter period of time and refresh it after expires (this is done silently). Refreshing a token will send access/refresh token pair to obtain new access/token pair.

Refresh token is validated every time when it is used. Therefore, by the time it is requesting a new token if the user has been removed from the active directory, refresh token will not be valid and will not be able obtain new token pair. As a result the user will be signed out.

What my suggestion by going through your scenario is to reduce the token expiry time to a shorter period of time like 30mins - 60mins. That would not make a huge impact to your application's performance.

[Reference for more details about tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)